# Migration from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3 - Duplicated websites

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, websites, magento2.3.4

I migrated from Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 2.3.4 using Data Migration Tool.

I follow the Settings - Data - Delta steps but at least i obtain duplicated websites/views of my site.

When I try to access to one category on my site I obtain the following error message: "There has been an error processing your request - The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again".

Please can you help me to solve the issue?
[image]

Comment: you remove theme id the database after run the setup and reindex command

Comment: Hi vincent, have you check the website code, store code and store view code? Moreover, have you take a look in the database of your store id that linked into the category?

Comment: have you tried drop your database , then re run the migration?

Comment: I am assuming you have found a solution by now, but did you re-index? Can you post your solution here?